# Intentional overlap fixed text with parallax

Tags: jquery, css, parallax

I'm trying to achieve this effect on the menu: http://www.tokiolab.it/

I want to be able to change colors while scroll through the slides.

This is what I have so far: http://tinyurl.com/6uqdjmq

But the overlapping is working so well that the menus are in top of each other, and I don't want that.

Is there any solution?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem correctly, your header is  showing when scrolling for fist and second slide.

First of all, there are same header elements in first and second section. Remove it from there
 and put it after container div. Also in header style. Remove `position:fixed`.

**Edit::**
You have to still remove the header from the both the places and put header(without class=dark) right after div container. and give it z-index 100. Also you have to attach a function on scrolling.

```
scrollorama.onBlockChange(function() {
    alert('You just scrolled to block#'+scrollorama.blockIndex);
     //Change the css properties of header using jquery .css() method.
});
```

You can change the color of header for each block by playing with this method.

Comment: There are the same elements in the first and second section. Yes. One menu is white, other menu is pink. But I want the pink one to show when the second section reach the top. If I remove the `position:fixed` I will have the menu on top of each slide, and I don't want that.

Comment: Ok i misunderstood the problem. Still you cant use position:fixed with top:0px as it will make your second header on top of your first header . You can  change the css of header using jquery, when you are scrolling.

Comment: Yes, but that won't do the overlapping effect that I'm trying to achieve like in here: http://cl.ly/HKcZ

Comment: I get your idea, and it's nice... but again, it won't do the filling effect on the transition.